# Having Xubuntu at its minimal display level,need the actual version of xubuntu with the eye candy features!

Tags: xubuntu, display, effects, preferences

I just installed xfce4 on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.And this is how it looks like,less eye candy, This is how it looks like

[image]

But i just need the desktop to be like the below, as i have Graphics card support,which works good on my Ubuntu 3d,How can i make this work on Xubuntu? I need the desktop to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first Image is how the vanilla xfce4 package is set up.

Your second Image is how the xubuntu-desktop package is set up.

Since you already have XFCE installed you need some more things to make it looks like that.

---

To make the first look like the latter you need to:

1. Download the Xubuntu theme

   > Open a Terminal and Type: `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-artwork` hit Enter and type your password.

   [image: Install via the software center]
2. Download the Xubuntu Icons

   > While still in the Terminal, Type `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-icon-theme`

   [image: Install via the software center]
3. And Download the Xubuntu wallpaper

   > Install them with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-wallpapers`

   [image: Install via the software center]

Then just adjust the panel's size and colors.

►Right Click on the Top panel ►Preferences ►Appearence and change the color.

While still in the preferences, go to the last tab to add the Applets you want.

If some of the Applets are not installed, install them with `sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies`

[image: Install via the software center]

To change the Theme and the Icons go to the ►Menu ►Configuration ►Appearance.

To change the Wallpaper right click the desktop and then Desktop configuration.

---

Alternatively you can just install the `xubuntu-desktop`package and it will set it up for you, though once you're about to login (if you didn't set it up to login automatically) you will have two choices:

1. XFCE4
2. Xubuntu

Though i think is redundant to have two if only the aesthetics are the only difference between the sessions.

Comment: could u just point me to the links u know about on how to do this

Comment: he has just told you exactly how to do it in the answer above...?

Comment: @WilliamFleming: He just updated it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Installing xubuntu-desktop package and login with the xubuntu session will indeed change the appearance from the default xfce to the nicer xubuntu look.

However, it won't make any use of the 3D card in your machine.

XFCE isn't a 3D accelerated environment, so it won't make much use of your card. It does have some eye-candy though, which you may want to enable. Go to the settings manager and click on 'Window Manager Tweaks'. Then enable compositing, and alter the settings for shadows and transparency according to taste.

If you want to go further, I recommend removing the bottom panel in XFCE and replacing it with a 3D accelerated dock. My personal favourite is called cairo-dock. This can also be set to run as a 3D accelerated dock by enabling OpenGL mode.